# Rolling Rates of past 1 month from two different variables in R

Tags: r

From the matrix below I would like to divide, 10/11 and 60/45 and so on…
that means divide the value for group_1 by the value for group_0 from the previous month
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(
  Date = c("8/31/2014", "9/30/2014", "10/31/2014", "11/31/2014"),
  Group_0 = c(11,60,41,4),
  Group_1 = c(46,10,45,5),
  Group_2 = c(90,8,12,56)
)
        Date Group_0 Group_1 Group_2
1  8/31/2014      11      46      90
2  9/30/2014      60      10       8
3 10/31/2014      41      45      12
4 11/31/2014       4       5      56

df %>%
  mutate(Output = lead(Group_1)/Group_0)

        Date Group_0 Group_1 Group_2    Output
1  8/31/2014      11      46      90 0.9090909
2  9/30/2014      60      10       8 0.7500000
3 10/31/2014      41      45      12 0.1219512
4 11/31/2014       4       5      56        NA
```